# Bulk Insert Multiple Pipe Data in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query to insert data from .lst file into table name AxisATM But when i try to insert it gives me error that

WHEN I REMOVES ALL ROWS FROM LST file except First ..It gives me Success msg saying 1 rows changed..

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 36. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Query :-

```
    BULK
INSERT dbo.ATMAxis
FROM 'c:\AGS_WINCORE_120901.lst'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = 'CHAR(13)'
)
GO
```

AGS_WINCORE_120901.lst :-

```
PRO1|......|00000000000|0| {Like it has 36 '|' separators}
```

Using Notepad++ i know Line End Characters are CR LF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected the problem lies in

```
ROWTERMINATOR = 'CHAR(13)'
```

I have Changed it to

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
```

Comment: Thanks YOU.  This was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says column 36 has more chanracters than that of column 36 of table's column. You need to increase the size of that column

Comment: I guess ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n' is creating problem. are they right if CR & LF Printing in NotePad++

Answer (score 0):

It seems the row terminator creates issue. If that's the case, try replacing `/r/n` with `Char(10)` it will solve the problem. Also, check for `char(13)`.

[This MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/transactsql/thread/a87b9fbb-40dc-4a2e-83df-eab150620122) has more information.

Comment: I tried both 'CHAR(13)' & 'CHAR(10)' as well 'CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)'...but nothing seems to be work